# appending node to xml file with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a routine in powershell that queries the index usage stats.  The query runs for each database on the server and pumps out an xml snippet.  I'm trying to get all of the results in one xml file.  All of the code works except for the piece that appends nodes to an existing xml file.  I've tried AppendNode and ImportNode with no results.  Here's the snippet that isn't working

```
$xml = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query... | ConvertTo-Xml

$file_xml = [xml](Get-Content $target_file) 
$index_nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("/Objects/Object")  
foreach($index_node in $index_nodes){
    $file_xml.ImportNode($index_node, $true)            
}               
$file_xml.Save($target_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble doing similar things working with XML in PowerShell. In most cases I believe it is the XML format of the file I am working with just does not like PowerShell. I can run the commands with no errors, look at my XML file and nothing was added. I usually end up treating the file like a normal text file. However...

For your instance, I think you might want to re-evaluate how you are querying for the information. You state it is run against each database when if you are using `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` you can get one query for every index used in any database on the instance. Which Kimberly Tripp offers a quick query that can be used [here](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Spring-cleaning-your-indexes-Part-I.aspx) (which this is the script used below).

That would in turn provide you with one XML file:

```
$indexStats = @"
SELECT getdate() AS RunTime
, DB_NAME(i.database_id) as DatabaseName
, OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id, i.database_id) as ObjectName
, i.user_seeks
, i.last_user_seek
, i.user_scans
, i.last_user_scan
, i.user_lookups
, i.last_user_lookup
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS i
WHERE object_id > 100
"@

$xml = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance  -Database master -Query $indexStats |
 ConvertTo-Xml
```

I understand you might have a reason for doing it against each individual database in your environment, but this seems to be more efficient and would be less code to keep up with in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. To replicate you're XML structure I used `ConvertTo-XML` to create two xml objects. The objects in the second one are appended to the first one and saved to disk.

```
$xml1 = dir -path C:\Users\andy | ? {$_.PsIsContainer} | ConvertTo-Xml
$xml2 = dir -path C:\ | ? {$_.PsIsContainer} | ConvertTo-Xml

$objectNodes = $xml2.SelectNodes('/Objects/Object')
if ($objectNodes) {
    foreach ($objectNode in $objectNodes) {
        $importedNode = $xml1.ImportNode($objectNode, $true)
        $xml1.DocumentElement.AppendChild($importedNode) | Out-Null
    }
 }

$xml1.Save("C:\Users\andy\Desktop\output.xml")
```